# Whitespace/margin around last item on navigation list

Tags: html, css

Can anyone give me a pointer on a site I've inherited. I'm more of an SEO guy than raw code and I'm not making any headway on this.

Have a look at http://www.edwardjackson.co.uk and you'll see whitespace around the last item in the left hand navigation list "Home Condition reports".

Can anyone give me a steer as to what's causing this & what to do about it?

What I think is the relevant part of css is:

```
.nav li ul li a {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #504c40;
    margin-left: -80px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.nav li ul li a:hover {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #504c40;
    margin-left: -80px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-image: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: underline;
```

Many Thanks - Dunc.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Tiago - no fiddle is necessary.  You can "Fiddle" with his actual site with Firebug.

Comment: you need to remove not only the height property but the margin-bottom property too.

Comment: Thank you all! I am now slightly better educated :)

I'd upvote you if I had the ability but I don't yet have sufficient reputation but my virtual gratitude is there all the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is actually the correct amount of whitespace.  The problem is that the other a elements have two lines of text, and therefore are "overflowing" with content.

The reason is that the `.nav li ul li a` element has a height of 18px on it, which is only slightly larger than a single line of text.  If you change that style to `height: auto;`, then the entire list will be consistent.  (Note: that style is on line 699 of your style.css stylesheet).

Comment: Someone is after us, cale. I just upvoted your answer and two secs later you got a downvote too x)

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a fixed `height` for your anchor elements.
Try using:

```
.nav li ul li a { height:auto; }
```

Comment: Yep, someone does NOT like this question and/or the answers that go along with it.  Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the 'height' property from the two classes:

1. .nav li ul li a
2. .nav li a

Answer (score 0):

in your class nav li ul li a you use the height attribute with 18px; if you change this it will look like it should be.

This how the code should look like:

```
.nav li ul li a {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #504c40;
    margin-left: -80px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.nav li ul li a:hover {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #504c40;
    margin-left: -80px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-image: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: underline;
```

Sidenote:
You could remove alot of attribute from .nav li ul li a:hover so your css looks alot cleaner. This is because all the attributes from hover will be inherited from .nav li ul li a

All you have to do is change the attributes that are different
So your code could look like this:

```
.nav li ul li a {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #504c40;
    margin-left: -80px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.nav li ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

offcourse this is not a must but could make your css code cleaner and faster to load.